# Given an abelian group with a divisor $D$ s.t. $L(D)$ gives projective embedding. Then $L(2D)$ is generated by degree 2 monomial elements of $L(D)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Given an abelian group torus $A=\frac{C^n}{\Lambda}$ with a divisor $D$ s.t. $L(D)$ gives projective embedding.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is $L(2D)$ generated by degree 2 monomial elements of $L(D)$? How do I see this.(I want to see the effect of Veronese embedding showing up somehow.) Riemann-Roch does not tell me this necessarily true? Is this true for large $n$ twist of $D$? Say $L(nD)$ for $n$ larger. Then $L(knD)$ is generated by degree $k$ monomial elements of $L(nD)$? How do I prove this? Hint only or reference only please.

Comment: Since $D$ is very ample you can use Hirzebruch–Riemann–Roch theorem to compute the dimension of $L(nD)$. On the other hand, you can calculate the, at least expected, dimension of the space generated by the monomials and compare the results.

Comment: @AlanMuniz The troublesome part is constant part $(1-g)$. This term shifts the dimension by a constant unless magically $L(K_A-nD)$ get rid of that term but for large $n$ this term should be turned off. I only know riemann-roch for surfaces and curves at best. For large $n$, $(1-g)$ is comparably small but this term still contributes non-trivially to the counting of sections unless $g=1$ which is elliptic curve.

Comment: You'll have to use some information about the manifold to calculate it effectively.

Comment: Notice that $K_A$ is trivial.

Comment: Another thing you'll use is the Kodaira vanishing theorem.

Comment: @AlanMuniz I think I could twist $D$ large enough to turn off $L(K_A-nD)$ part. As I assumed this abelian variety comes from some riemann surface. Then $L(nD)=nDeg(D)+(1-g)$. Say I want to see $L(2nD)=2nDeg(D)+(1-g)\sim 2L(nD)$ but $L(2nD)$ is not growing quadratically in $L(nD)$. The whole point is to see that if $D_1,D_2$ are two non-degenerate positive divisors of $A$ and their hermitian forms $H_1,H_2$ have $mH_1=nH_2,m,n\in Z$, then $D_1$ and $D_2$ induced embeddings differ by a veronese embedding and translation by group element. The translation by group element is clear.